# Textract Form Analysis, Java SDK 1.x

Tags: amazon-web-services, ocr

I'm looking to extract form data utilizing textract. I've tested with a PDF in the demo and results are great. Results using the SDK however are far from optimal, actually, completely inaccurate. If I use `StartDocumentAnalysisRequest/StartDocumentAnalysisResult` (asynchronous), I only get 1 block returned of type `PAGE`, never `KEY_VALUE_SET`. If I convert my PDF to an image and use the synchronous methods, I do get `KEY_VALUE_SET` back but results are completely inaccurate.

Does anyone know how I can utilize the asynchronous analysis functionality to retrieve form values as the documentation indicates?

Sample Code below:

```
        StartDocumentAnalysisResult startDocumentAnalysisResult = amazonTextract.startDocumentAnalysis(req);
        String startJobId = startDocumentAnalysisResult.getJobId();

        GetDocumentAnalysisResult documentAnalysisResult = null;

        String jobStatus = "IN_PROGRESS";

        while (jobStatus.equals("IN_PROGRESS")) {
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
                GetDocumentAnalysisRequest documentAnalysisRequest = new GetDocumentAnalysisRequest()
                        .withJobId(startJobId)
                        .withMaxResults(1);

                documentAnalysisResult = amazonTextract.getDocumentAnalysis(documentAnalysisRequest);
                jobStatus = documentAnalysisResult.getJobStatus();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error(e);
            }
        }

        if (!jobStatus.equals("IN_PROGRESS")) {
                List<Block> blocks = documentAnalysisResult.getBlocks();
                logger.error("block list size " + blocks.size());

                Map<String, Map<String, Block>> keyValueBlockMap = new HashMap<>();
                Map<String, Block> keyMap = new HashMap<>();
                Map<String, Block> valueMap = new HashMap<>();
                Map<String, Block> blockMap = new HashMap<>();

                for (Block block : blocks) {
                    logger.error("Block Type:" + block.getBlockType());
                    String blockId = block.getId();
                    blockMap.put(blockId, block);
                    if (block.getBlockType().equals("KEY_VALUE_SET")) {
                        if (block.getEntityTypes().contains("KEY")) {
                            keyMap.put(blockId, block);
                        } else {
                            valueMap.put(blockId, block);
                        }
                    }
                }
                keyValueBlockMap.put("keyMap", keyMap);
                keyValueBlockMap.put("valueMap", valueMap);
                keyValueBlockMap.put("blockMap", blockMap);

                Map<String, String> keyValueRelationShip = getKeyValueRelationShip(keyValueBlockMap);
                for (String key : keyValueRelationShip.keySet()) {
                    logger.error("Key: " + key);
                    logger.error("Value: " + keyValueRelationShip.get(key));
                }
            }
```

Synchronous path which results in completely horrible results:

```
AnalyzeDocumentRequest request = new AnalyzeDocumentRequest() .withFeatureTypes(FeatureType.FORMS) .withDocument(new Document(). withS3Object(new com.amazonaws.services.textract.model.S3Object() .withName(objectName) .withBucket(awsHelper.getS3BucketName()))); 

AnalyzeDocumentResult result = amazonTextract.analyzeDocument(request);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the recommended version for the **AWS SDK for Java**. You are using a old version and not the recommended one.

I have tested the [AWS SDK for Java V2](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2) and I am able to get lines and text that lines up with the AWS Management Console.

[image]

You can find textTract V2 examples in the repo linked above.

I am able to get to lines and the corresponding text by using **software.amazon.awssdk.services.textract.TextractClient**.

For example when i debug through the code using the same PNG as I used in the console, i get the proper result.

[image]

Comment: I'm going to mark your answer as THE answer because I know I shouldve been using v2 and was just being stubborn. This actually wasn't my problem though, it was the fact that I had set maxResults to 1 haha whoops

Comment: I am glad you got it working

Comment: I will say that the form analysis results are still very much not ideal. I see that the result you screenshot is from a detected line, which I can replicate but the form values from form analysis is completely different from what I can see in the AWS console. I tried testing with a basic 1040 tax form from the internet, for example, and the console will detect all of the form fields and values but the result utilizing the SDK (v1 or v2) is mostly broken.

Comment: If you believe the Textract Java SDK is not working properly -- please log an issue in Github... https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2

Comment: thanks i've created an issue